# Printers visible to exe not visible to web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

Solved - thanks to Steve.  The problem was that the App Pool I used was using the default App Pool Identity, which doesn't have sufficient privileges.  Changing to an App Pool that used an account with sufficient privileges fixed the problem.

I have a simple C# class to get a list of available printers.  When called from within a simple Console app, it returns the complete list of locally defined printers (9 printers).  When called from the code behind in an aspx web app, it only returns the default printer.  The web app is installed and runs as a user that is a local administrator on the server, and all printers are defined within that user's profile.

Note - I remote desktop to the server and run the console exe app there and it shows all the printers.  I am trying to get a list of all the printers defined on the server.

Is there some security issue that I am missing?

Class code:

```
using System.Management;

/// <summary>
/// Returns a list of printers available on the current system.
/// </summary>
public static class PrinterList
{
public class Printer
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string server { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public string portname { get; set; }
    public string sharename { get; set; }
}
public static Printer[] GetInstalledPrinterList()
{
    Printer[] printers = new Printer[0];

    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * from Win32_Printer");
    ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
    {
        string name = printer.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
        if ((!name.ToLower().Contains("send to onenote")) &&
            (!name.ToLower().Contains("xps document writer")) &&
            (!name.ToLower().Contains("print to pdf")) &&
            (!name.ToLower().Contains(" fax")) &&
            (!name.ToLower().Equals("fax")))
        {
            string server = "";
            if (printer.GetPropertyValue("ServerName") != null)
                server = printer.GetPropertyValue("ServerName").ToString();
            string location = "";
            if (printer.GetPropertyValue("Location") != null)
                location = printer.GetPropertyValue("Location").ToString();
            string portname = "";
            if (printer.GetPropertyValue("PortName") != null)
                portname = printer.GetPropertyValue("PortName").ToString();
            string sharename = "";
            if (printer.GetPropertyValue("ShareName") != null)
                sharename = printer.GetPropertyValue("ShareName").ToString();

            Printer newPrinter = new Printer();
            newPrinter.name = name;
            newPrinter.server = server;
            newPrinter.location = location;
            newPrinter.portname = portname;
            newPrinter.sharename = sharename;

            Printer[] newlist = new Printer[printers.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0;i < printers.Length; i++)
            {
                newlist[i] = printers[i];
            }
            newlist[printers.Length] = newPrinter;
            printers = newlist;
        }
    }
    return printers;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your asp.net c# code runs on your server not on client's computer. This is really important fact to remember.

By calling get printers on asp.net you are basically getting the available printers connected to your server not the ones from client.

Edit: Turns out that you were using the default account for the app pool. By using an account with admin right for the app pool solves the problem.

Comment: That is exactly what I want - the printers on the server.  When I run the exe it is on the server also.  But the exe (using the same class) returns all the printers, while the web app only shows the one default printer.

Comment: @KimCrosser typically your asp.net will be hosted on IIS which runs under IISxxx user account, either config IIS to use an admin account or give that IIS account admin permission. You also need to give your site "full trust" permission in IIS.

Comment: The site, and my web app, are both running with .NET Trust Levels = Full (internal).  Both the site and my web app are also using a logon account that is a member of the Administrators Group on the server.

Comment: @KimCrosser How are you running them? Within IIS or some other host server?

Comment: Under IIS.  This server has just the one site, under which my web app is installed.

Comment: FYI - this is a Windows 2008R2 server, running IIS 7.5.

Comment: @KimCrosser you mentioned logon account. You mean the account you used to login or the one IIS uses internally? Those two are very different. You need to make sure IIS uses an account with admin right instead of the original IISXXXX account which has limited right

Comment: Aha!  You got me pointed in the correct direction.  The problem was the App Pool that I was using was using the default App Pool Identity.  When I changed to use an App Pool that used the logon account with admin rights, the problem was solved.